# Immo coil - Resistance, Reactance and Impedance - Differences needed

Tags: inductor, impedance, reactance, lcr

Since I work in an automobile lock manufacturing company, I was measuring the DC resistance of an Immo coil using a multimeter (used in automobiles for security purposes) and found out the value was about 6 Ω.

When I measured the same using a LCR meter (@125 kHz, V: 2 V) the value came out to be Rs = 22 Ω.

I know there is a difference due to reactance of coil at a particular frequency but still wanted to dig deep and understand how is 6 Ω and 22 Ω related by some mathematical formula?

Can anyone explain me regarding resistance, reactance and impedance wrt to an Immo coil with some examples?

Comment: Maybe the meter was giving you the equivalent parallel resistance.

Comment: What's an Immo coil?

Comment: Immo coil = Immolizer coil.

When the Vehicle Key is inserted into the Ignition Cylinder, a signal is sent from the Induction Coil of Anti-Theft Immobilizer that energizes the electronic transponder in the key. The electronic transponder in the key responds to the Induction Coil of Anti-Theft Immobilizer with a signal.